# how to prevent other developer to create existing file in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file

I was asked this question in one of interview - how to stop other developer in team from creating duplicate class in Xcode.
I really have no clue on this .

Experts can help me on this.

Comment: The question probably wasn't how to stop them creating a duplicate, because the compiler would catch that and throw an error anyway. the question was probably how to prevent another developer extending your class. to which the answer would be to use the `final` keyword in the class definition to prevent subclassing further

Comment: @janardanau - is the intension to avoid duplicates ?

Comment: You can't create duplicate files Xcode won't allow this and neither duplicate class compiler won't allow this. I think **Scriptable** is right question might be avoiding subclass and with `final` you can do that.

Comment: @Scriptable - I told samething about final keyword but the person was still ..insisting on same question, and hence I noted down the question and asking here..

Comment: Then the answer would be that you can't prevent them doing it, but the compiler would not allow it anyway as it would throw an error

Comment: @Scriptable - you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question probably wasn't how to stop them creating a duplicate file, because the compiler would catch that and throw an error anyway. So if this was the question your answer would be simply something like:

> You cannot prevent them from creating the file, but the compiler would throw an error and not allow the project to build.

I think the question would of been

> How to prevent another developer extending your class.

to which the answer would be to use the final keyword in the class definition to prevent subclassing further.

Reference:

[Documentation - Preventing Overrides](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html)